# hiding query string with .htaccess inside a folder

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url

i want to turn this url:

```
http://mysite.com/images/?url=20121206/test.jpg&zoom=120&f=g
```

into this:

```
http://mysite.com/images/20121206/test.jpg?zoom=120&f=g
```

the  .htaccess  file inside /images/ folder

I googled many regex but not working..please help!

or can do this outside the images folder?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule images/(.*) images/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: the image still didn't change

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job I believe.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=(.*)
RewriteRule /images/ /images/%1 [QSA, R]
```

Comment: Edited it. Just realised you aren't specifying the index.php file in your URL.

Comment: Try the new version in a browser and let me know what it rewrites the URL to.